# Make bind() function to live bind function

Tags: jquery

I have some problems to find the correct synthax. This is my old code:

```
jQuery("#file1").live('change', function(){
     jQuery('.pic_upload').fadeIn();    
});
```

I had to change it because of IE issues. This is my new one:

```
jQuery("#file1").bind((jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 9) ? 'propertychange' :  'change',
   function(){ jQuery('.pic_upload').show();
  });
```

Ho can I implement the 'live' to my new function?

Comment: Why exactly do you need the live method?

Comment: not sure propertychange works with live

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to change fadeIn() to show() and bind to 'propertychange' in versions of IE before 9. In that case, this should work:

```
jQuery("#file1").live((jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 9) ? 'propertychange' :  'change', function(){
     jQuery('.pic_upload').show();   
});
```

Comment: I need the bind() too, otheriwse it does not work.I need something like live().bind()....or so